# WiFi device speed priority

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, internet-speed

I am having a weird issue. I have a high speed internet at home and a WiFi router.
I have two computers - my Sony laptop (win8) and my girlfriends Macbook.

Somewhy when I am downloading something - my maximum speed is 100 KiB/s at most, while she easily gets 1Mb/s
Even when we are downloading at the same time.

What could be the issue? My router is a gateway, I looked through the settings but couldn't find anything related to maximum speed or device priority.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "related to this issue," your router is responsible for all sorts of settings that could have an impact on your network. Are you saying the setting are configured correctly and wouldn't be related, or that you don't see anything that could have an impact?? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I meant that I couldn't find anything related to speed or priority of devices,, sorry about the confusion